# Java, is this a declaration?

Tags: java

```
public void sendMessage(View view){
//todo
}
```

Is `View view` declaring (giving a name ( "`view`" ) to?) class `View`? So it can be initialized later (`view = new View();`)?

Comment: It was difficult to choose the best answer as all are supplementing each other.The runner up answers (also concisely) mention different things like for example what `View` is while the chosen answer has also helpful examples.However I had difficulties comprehending the answers because of the inexplicity of the answers.

It turns out that I need 9 more "reputation" to upvote so I'll do this then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No this means when the function is called view will be passed as an parameter.

Eg:

```
public int sum (int num1, int num2){
    return num1+num2;
}
```

Now you would call this like:

```
System.out.printn(sum(1,2));
```

This would print 3.

In your case where would call the function sendMessage. You would do it like

```
View view= new view();
sendMessage(view);
```

EDIT:

```
public void sendMessage(View view){
    // Here you can use view as if it is already set you don't need to create a new view.
   // Example you might want some attributes from view to send message.
   System.out.println("View name" + view.getName());
   System.out.println("View id" + view.getId());
   // Note this is just an example. you can use attributes from view in here.
}
```

Comment: It is a variable that you can use. Read http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html

Comment: Can you amend your answer please?

Comment: What amends do you need ?

Answer (score 1):

"View" is your data type. "view" is your variable. It looks like you are passing the "view" as a parameter to a function to be used locally within that function.

view = new View() can be initialized within that function as long as "view" is globally declared.

Answer (score 1):

`view` is a parameter of the method `sendMessage`. Technically, it is creating a new variable, called `view`, of type `View` that has a special ability: it is initialized with the value you pass when calling the `sendMessage` method.

Comment: can you explain "it is initialized with the value"?

Comment: It means that its initial value is the value of the variable passed as parameter to it. If you have ```sendMessage(v)```, where ```v``` is a variable of type ```View```, the method variable ```view``` gets in this specific call the value of ```v```, like you have written ```View view = v``` somewhere in your code. Hope it is clear enough :).